# How to send udp to udp node.js server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, udp

I'm very new to this so I really don't know what I'm doing, but I've setup a node.js udp server.  I want to send a packet to it from the client (being from a website), but I don't know how to do that in javascript/ or if it's even possible.  I'm not looking on how to send a packet from a node.js client to server, but rather how to write a website to send a packet to a node.js udp server.  Not sure if that made sense, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

You may be interested in this tutorial:

http://fzysqr.com/2011/02/28/nodechat-js-using-node-js-backbone-js-socket-io-and-redis-to-make-a-real-time-chat-app/

It goes through how to create a chat application in node.js in very fine detail, he even shows how to use Socket.io (a browser js library) to utilize web sockets for realtime, low latency responses.

And as Phihag hinted at, UDP isn't good for this sort of application because *UDP does not guarantee your packet will get to its destination*. You definitely want to use TCP Sockets in this case.

More reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Comment: TCP does not guarantee your packet will get to its destination either... the difference is that TCP tells you when it did, UDP doesn't, so to speak.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot send UDP datagrams from a webbrowser (i.e. JavaScript). What you can do is contact a webserver (for example via AJAX or websocket) and execute a server-side program (in php or node.js or so) to send the UDP datagram. You can send a UDP datagram with the server-side programming language's native socket module ([Python](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html), [php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), [node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html)).

However, why are you using UDP in the first place? You'll have to handle retransmissions, reordering and the like, and since webbrowsers can only talk via TCP, you're not getting any of the advantages of UDP.

Comment: I'm creating a chat app and want to use udp to send/receive messages.

Comment: then can I do tcp from a webrowser?

Comment: @Derek For a chat app, I can't imagine a reason why one would use UDP instead of TCP. The disadvantages are: Retransmission must be implemented, ordering must be implemented (also needed for large packets), and possibly even congestion avoidance. With TCP, you get all that for free, and have an easier time going through firewalls. So why are you using UDP instead of TCP?

Comment: @Derek Well, you can use [websockets](http://websocket.org/), which is as close as you can get to TCP. All other protocols (which are basically polling the webserver for news) are way more abstract than that (opposite to UDP) and based on regular HTTP, which is based on TCP.

Comment: @phihag : For our information, since Chrome v33 you can manipulate udp by using JS API https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp. Not sure that all browsers follow Chrome on this point...

Comment: @l.cotonea That's an internal function for chrome extensions though; not for a web application. Allowing arbitrary UDP or TCP in the browser would lead to the exposure of significant security holes since any web application could now talk to any device on your local network.

Comment: ... And there is a W3C draft about a TCP and UDP Socket API (http://www.w3.org/TR/tcp-udp-sockets/ ). Maybe in a few years... :)

Comment: nodejs does not run in the browser but in the server side, so why not being able to use UDP or anything else ?

Comment: You can run UDP in web browsers with WebRTC