# Send udp packet from chrome

Tags: javascript, udp, websocket

Researching on the internet ( [How to send udp to udp node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451522/how-to-send-udp-to-udp-node-js-server), [JavaScript WebSockets with UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657033/javascript-websockets-with-udp)) I have found that it is not possible to send udp packets with javascript.

On the other hand some pages claim that chrome browser is able to do so. For example the link:

http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/chrome-tcp-udp

claims that google chrome is able to send udp packets. Maybe I am doing something wrong. If it is true that chrome can send udp packets I will appreciate if someone can post a *hello world* example. I have tried the example from the link I showed and it does not work. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: From that page: "*Chrome Canary now has support for raw TCP and UDP sockets in its **‘experimental’ APIs**. These features are **only available for extensions** and, although documented, are hidden for the moment*". What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: You are right I should paid more atention when reading instead of jumping straight to the code. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess that should be an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the linked page](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/chrome-tcp-udp):

> Chrome Canary now has support for raw TCP and UDP sockets in its
>   *‘experimental’ APIs*. These features are *only available for extensions*
>   and, although documented, are hidden for the moment.

So, develop an extension and it should work. Actually, that article from May '12 seems to be outdated as the [`chrome.socket` module](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) now has lost its `experimental` status. For the HelloWorld, you might check out their [udp sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/udp) which is linked from the official pages.

Comment: Apparently UDP sockets are not possible in extensions anymore. It was possible at one point, but they disabled it due to security concerns -- restricting it only to Chrome apps, which are being ended/phased-out now as well. :/