# OSC values to web

Tags: javascript, python, osc

Looking to output OSC output values to web app.
Preferably Python or JavaScript.

Is this at all possible?

Can anyone point me in the direction of a library if this functionality exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases OSC is based on UDP, rarely TCP. So you must ensure, that both client and server can send or read, respectively, UDP. On the server side this is possible with node.js. On the client side here is a possible solution: [Send udp packet from chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964972/send-udp-packet-from-chrome)

Python can do this without any problems. There are even libraries for that. I can recommend this page for some [implementations](http://opensoundcontrol.org/implementations)

Answer (score 0):

This Python gist works as a bridge between WebSockets and UDP-Servers for OSC Messages: https://gist.github.com/adzialocha/48544bd61183da666e6d including a HTTP server.

For reading / writing the OSC messages in JavaScript you can use this library: https://github.com/adzialocha/osc-js (comes with some examples).