# ExtJS Sending Data To Server Over UDP

Tags: javascript, extjs, udp, logstash

I have a Sencha application and I want to send logs to server. I have configured Docker with ELK containers (Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana) and they are properly working (I know that because I can send data to Kibana via an iOS application from XCode).

However I want to do this in ExtJS. I am currently having the **error ext-modern-all-debug.js?_dc=20161118152155:15274 POST http://localhost:49160/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. I have setup ELK containers as I mentioned and logstash is configured as **0.0.0.0:49160->5002/udp** while Elasticsearch and Kibana using TCP.

Is it some sort of udp/tcp problem? How can I get rid of it and send data to Kibana, or simply Logstash?

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot send UDP datagrams from a webbrowser (i.e. JavaScript).

Source and further information: [How to send udp to udp node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451522/how-to-send-udp-to-udp-node-js-server)

Comment: So you are saying I cannot send data to Logstash from my ExtJS application under configurations above (logstash is configured as 0.0.0.0:49160->5002/udp while Elasticsearch and Kibana using TCP). What would you suggest? Should I change logstash configuration to tcp?

Comment: I would suggest that you use a server-side middleware that supports both UDP and TCP. From the link I provided: "You can send a UDP datagram with the server-side programming language's native socket module (Python, php, node.js)."